# Set date range in PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, date

I want to ask

**How to set date range in PHP ?**

I have row data in a mysql database

**date_from : 2016-11-01 and date_to : 2016-11-15**

What I want to achieve is I want to display and error **"Duplicate date"** if the user input

1. date_from : 2016-11-01 , date_into : 2016-11-15 (both date same as range)
2. date from : 2016-01-02 , date_into : 2016-11-17 (One of the date is in the range)
3. date from : 2016-11-02 , date_into : 2016-11-04 (both data is inside the range)

The code as below

```
<?php
    $connect      = mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "", "");
    global $connect;   

    if(isset($_POST['SendDate']))
    {
        $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
        $dtfrom_user    = $_POST['dtfrom'];
        $dtfrom_convert = strtotime($dtfrom_user);
        $dtfrom         = date("Y-m-d", $dtfrom_convert);

        $dtto_user      = $_POST['dtfrom'];
        $dtto_convert   = strtotime($dtto_user);
        $dtto           = date("Y-m-d", $dtto_convert);

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM movement WHERE user_id = '".$user_id."' AND dtfrom >= '".$dtfrom."' AND <= dtto '".$dtto."'";
        $get = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
        if($get && mysqli_num_rows($get) > 0 )
        {
            while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($get))
            {
                $dtfrom_db = $result['dtfrom'];
                $dtto_db   = $result['dtto'];

                if(($dtfrom >= $dtfrom_db) && ($dtto <= $dtto_db))
                {
                    echo "error";   
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "Added";
                }
            }
        mysqli_free_result($get);
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Not found!";
            echo mysqli_error($connect);
        }
    }
?>
<form action="date.php" method="POST">  
    <table> 
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>User ID :</td>
            <td><input type ="text" name="user_id"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Date from : </td>
            <td><input type ="date" name="dtfrom"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Date to : </td>
            <td><input type ="date" name="dtto"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>    
    <p><input type ="submit" name="SendDate" value="Submit"> </p>               
</form>
```

p/s: I already tried the solutions in other questions but have no luck so far.

Appreciate if someone can help.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried BETWEEN operator of MYSQL?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Nope. i'm not sure how to do BETWEEN operator of MYSQL

Comment: [W3c School BETWEEN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp)

Comment: yes. i know that . but from above question , how to execute it . is it $sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE user_id = '".$user_id."' AND dtfrom >= '".$dtfrom."' BETWEEN <= dtto '".$dtto."'"; ?

Comment: here's a sample. "SELECT * FROM table WHERE dt BETWEEN CAST(from_date AS DATE) AND CAST(to_date AS DATE)"

Comment: is it a typo error when your writing the question here that you put `<=` between `AND` and `dtto`?

Comment: try this `"SELECT * FROM movement WHERE user_id = '".$user_id."' AND 
dtfrom BETWEEN CAST('".$dtfrom."' AS DATE) AND CAST('".$dtto."' AS DATE) AND 
dtto BETWEEN CAST('".$dtfrom."' AS DATE) AND CAST('".$dtto."' AS DATE)"`

Comment: ok. i'll try it first . i will let you know .

Comment: Hye, i've tried your suggestion code . It works on no.1 and no.2 . but it didn't work if the both input is in between the date range . I don't know why

Comment: try this `SELECT * FROM movement WHERE user_id = '".$user_id."' AND (dtfrom BETWEEN CAST('".$dtfrom."' AS DATE) AND CAST('".$dtto."' AS DATE) OR dtto BETWEEN CAST('".$dtfrom."' AS DATE) AND CAST('".$dtto."' AS DATE))`

Comment: still not working . i don't know why it cannot read the error if the input is no.3   (both input is between dtfrom and dtto) .. :(

Comment: nope . still not working either. . got really frustrated. it's been a week i try to figure out the solutions. no luck so far . . thanks for the response btw :)

Comment: try to combine my answers something like this `"SELECT * FROM movement WHERE user_id = '".$user_id."' AND dtfrom BETWEEN CAST('".$dtfrom."' AS DATE) AND CAST('".$dtto."' AS DATE) AND dtto BETWEEN CAST('".$dtfrom."' AS DATE) AND CAST('".$dtto."' AS DATE) AND (dtfrom BETWEEN CAST('".$dtfrom."' AS DATE) AND CAST('".$dtto."' AS DATE) OR dtto BETWEEN CAST('".$dtfrom."' AS DATE) AND CAST('".$dtto."' AS DATE))"`

Comment: still not work .. have you try the code from your end ? is it work ?

Comment: Bobby Tables rides again! http://bobby-tables.com/